# Computing matter power spectrum using FFT

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics, simulations

I have a 3-dimensional density field from a big N-body simulation, and I would like to compute the matter power spectrum $P(k)$ to see how it compares with the one observed by Planck etc. I know that the process involves computing the FFT of the over-density field, $\hat{
\delta}(k)$, and then average $|\hat{
\delta}(k)|^2$ over spherical bins in the $k$ space. My question is, which $k$ are sampled? And how to normalize the result so that it takes into account the number of density bins $N^3$ and the comoving box size $L$?